# Parsing CSV with TextFieldParser with fields containing double quotes

Tags: c#, textfieldparser

I'm trying to parse a file that contains fields that seem valid to me but fail using C# TextFieldParser.
Here is an example of problematic line:

> "abc","def","this is container "A" in room","another field"

```
using TextFieldParser parser = new(Filename);
parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
parser.SetDelimiters(RawFileDelimiter);
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

    // do some validation
}
```

I did not find any parameter in TextFieldParser to go through this case. I guess I could use regex to parse it but that will make the whole thing much more complicated.
Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It is not valid - quotes inside a quoted value must be escaped. You might need to use a regex to split the fields instead of a `TextFieldParser`/

Comment: Why are you not using a proper CSV parser, like CSVHelper ? https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: @Neil Will it parse a line like I describe and return "this is container "A" in room" ?